# Expected pair of collisions in two choice hashing

Tags: algorithm, hash

In two choice hashing(with chaining), two random hash functions h1, h2 are selected to hash n keys to m positions. The process goes like this:

Insert all n keys sequentially, by evaluating for each key x, the two hash functions, and adding the key to the shorter list of those indexed by h1(x), h2(x). Let Y be the number of pairs (x, x') such that they end up in the same linked list. What would the expectation of Y(E[Y]) be like?

Assume h1, h2 hash keys uniformly and independently

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: but it's about randomized algorithm

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Not saying you're doing the wrong thing, but it's a math problem that's central to an important programming problem.  The low-level details of that programming problem are completely specified.  (Of course, cs.stackexchange.com also works, probably better, for this sort of thing.)

Comment: With that said, I don't know how to analyse this.  Cuckoo hashing has a pretty analysis because there's a natural analogy between the case where cuckoo fails and a random graph with m vertices and n edges containing a cycle.  There might be a fancy trick where you find an invariant of some parameter of the bin size distribution here, but I don't see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that there is a clean analytic solution to this problem.

But it is very tractable to produce numerical approximations for the case of a large number of buckets.  Let `x` be the ratio between the number of keys stored and the number of buckets.  Let `fn(x)` be the expected portion of buckets with `n` keys and `Fn(x)` be the expected portion of buckets with at most `n` keys.

Then trivially `Fn(x) = f0(x) + f1(x) + ... + fn(x)`.  And also `fn'(x)` is the probability that with a key add a bucket of size `n-1` will be added to, minus the probability that with a key add, a bucket of size `n` will be to.

The probability that a bucket of size `n` will be added to next is the probability that the first hash function chooses a bucket of size `n` and the second chooses one of size at least `n`, plus the probability that the first hash function chooses a bucket of size greater than `n` and the second chooses one of size `n`.  The probability of choosing a bucket of size greater than `n` is simply `1 - Fn(x)`.  So this probability is `fn(x)(1 - Fn-1(x)) + (1 - Fn(x))fn(x)`.

That makes `fn'(x) = fn-1(x)(1 - Fn-2(x)) + (1 - Fn-1(x))fn-1(x) -  fn(x)(1 - Fn-1(x)) - (1 - Fn(x))fn(x)`.  Which is a horribly non-linear system of equations and there is no need to expect any nice solution to it.  But it is also amenable to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods and you shouldn't need too many terms to get accurate estimates since the portion heavily filled buckets falls off faster than exponentially.  (To see why, convince yourself that if `n` is significantly larger than `x`, then `fn+1'(x)` is approximately `fn2(x)`.  The repeated squaring of small terms means that there is a very sharp falloff from `fn(x) < 0.01` to `fn(x) < 0.00000001`.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on m. For m being O(n^(3/2)), E[Y] = O(1).